# How to compare the second line with the first line in one single file using perl?

Tags: perl, compare

I am new to Perl, Currently, I am using Perl to do some text processing. There are four columns in the input file, separated by tab. I want to find the minimum of column 3 and maximum of column 4 and put them in one line for the same ID. Below shows how the input file look like:

```
A   A1  1  5
A   A1  9  18
A   A1  23 40
A   A2  20 30
A   A2  35 43
B   A1  2  10
B   A1  12 30
B   A1  35 100
C   A9  2  40
C   A9  45 70
```

My desired output:

```
A   A1 1  40
A   A2 23 43
B   A1 2  100
C   A9 2  70
```

Comment: Loop through the input, split each row and keep track of the highest/lowest values encountered in a hash.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows the person asking has not put any effort in solving the problem.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl Please don't close questions like that. That's where you use *too broad*. Also, questions aren't required to show effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading data file line by line, using the combination of first two columns as key of a record hash, and rembering in that hash the minimum column three and maximum column four. If you want to keep the order of those keys, also push them to an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(switch say);

use Data::Dumper;

my (%record, @key);

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @field = split /\s+/;
    my $key = join "\t", @field[0,1];
    push @key, $key unless $record{$key};
    if (!$record{$key}{min} || $record{$key}{min} > $field[2]) {
        $record{$key}{min} = $field[2];
    }
    if (!$record{$key}{max} || $record{$key}{max} < $field[3]) {
        $record{$key}{max} = $field[3];
    }
}

for my $key (@key) {
    print (join "\t", $key, $record{$key}{min}, $record{$key}{max}, "\n");
}
```

Comment: Your codes work well, is there anyway it can be processed faster? since I have about 56 million lines in my input files..

Comment: @user3682472 It depends on the characters of your data. Also, if you do not care about the order of the output, you can avoid that `@key` array, and use `while (my ($key, $val) = each %record) { ... }` to output the `%record` hash.

Answer (score 2):

Perl from command line,

```
perl -anE'
  $k = join "\t", @F[0,1];
  $h{$k} or push @r, $k;
  (!defined or $_ >$F[2]) and $_ = $F[2] for $h{$k}{m};
  ($_ <$F[3])             and $_ = $F[3] for $h{$k}{M};
}{
  say join "\t", $_, @{$h{$_}}{qw(m M)} for @r
' file
```

output

```
A       A1      1       40
A       A2      20      43
B       A1      2       100
C       A9      2       70
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'input-data.txt';

# Keep track of the current minimum and maximum
# values while we read the file.
#
my (%val1_min, %val2_max);

while (<$fh>)   ## loop through lines of file
{
  chomp;        ## remove trailing "\n" character

  # Split on sequences of whitespace
  #
  my ($key1, $key2, $val1, $val2) = split /\s+/;

  # Record a new minimum if there is no old
  # minimum, or if the old minimum is higher
  # than the current value.
  #
  $val1_min{$key1}{$key2} = $val1
    if !defined($val1_min{$key1}{$key2})
    or $val1_min{$key1}{$key2} > $val1;

  # Record a new maximum if there is no old
  # maximum, or if the old maximum is lower
  # than the current value.
  #
  $val2_max{$key1}{$key2} = $val2
    if !defined($val2_max{$key1}{$key2})
    or $val2_max{$key1}{$key2} < $val2;
}

# Now we need to produce some output.
#    

# Loop through the first level of keys.
#
for my $key1 (sort keys %val1_min)
{
  # Loop through the second level of keys.
  #
  for my $key2 (sort keys %{$val1_min{$key1}})
  {
    # Print a line of output to STDOUT.
    #
    printf(
      "%-04s %-04s %3d %3d\n",   ## formatting string
      $key1,                     ## first key
      $key2,                     ## second key
      $val1_min{$key1}{$key2},   ## minimum first value
      $val2_max{$key1}{$key2},   ## maximum second value
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using command line perl:

```
perl -MList::Util=max,min -lane '
    $k = join "\t", splice @F, 0, 2;
    push @k, $k if !$v{$k};
    push @{$v{$k}[$_]}, $F[$_] for (0..$#F);
  }{
    print join "\t", $_, min(@{$v{$_}[0]}), max(@{$v{$_}[1]}) for @k;
  ' file.txt
```

Outputs:

```
A       A1      1       40
A       A2      20      43
B       A1      2       100
C       A9      2       70
```